# How to set onclicklistener from a different activitys class?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

How can I set `onClickListener` of a button that belongs to a different activity?
I am using `sharedPreferences` and I want to create a logout button on a different activity. The activity which opens at launch should not have the logout button. That's why I don't have all the `sharedPreferences` code in the profile activity.

**HomeActivity class**:

```
//UserSessionManager class
UserSessionManager session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    //start new activity when fab is clicked
    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Profile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    session = new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    //check if user is logged in
    //if the user is not logged in
    if (session.checkLogin()) {
        finish();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

    //get variables
    String username = user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);
    String age = user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_AGE);
    String firstName = user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_FIRSTNAME);


    EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    EditText etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
```

I want the logout button to be in the profile activity.

Here is the **profile class**:

```
Button bLogOut;
UserSessionManager sessionManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
}
public void sendSession(final UserSessionManager userSession) {
    bLogOut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLogOut);

    bLogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            userSession.logoutUser();
        }
    });
}
```

After doing many different things I created the send session method which receives the session variable from the `HomeActivity` class as a parameter. I still got a `nullpointerexception`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a receiver in your HomeActivity.class like this,

```
public BroadcastReceiver logoutReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            /Do what ever you want.
        }
    };
```

Now register and unregister your receiver in your HomeActvity.class

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.saim.logoutReceiver");
        registerReceiver(logoutReceiver, intentFilter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        try {
            super.onDestroy();
            unregisterReceiver(logoutReceiver);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException i) {

        }
    }
```

Now just send your broadcast from any activty like this

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.saim.logoutReceiver"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onActivityResult` to handle the logout button action:

HomeActivity Class:

```
/* keep this static final variables on a separate file */
public static final int LOGOUT_ACTION = 1;
public static final int REQUEST_LOGOUT = 2;
public static final int RESULT_LOGOUT = 3;
/* ============== */


 //start new activity when fab is clicked
final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, IntentUtil.REQUEST_LOGOUT);
    }
});


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_LOGOUT && resultCode == RESULT_LOGOUT) {
        //Handle logout here
    }
```

ProfileActivity Class:

```
bLogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_LOGOUT, intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How I normally handle login and logout is to do this type of pattern.

I check if the user is logged in on startup, then I launch my Authentication Activity. If the user is not logged in, I put the user to the login Activity until they do login.

MainActivity -(needs login)-> AuthenticationActivity -> (RESULT_OK or RESULT_CANCELLED) -> MainActivity relaunches AuthenticationActivity if RESULT_CANCELLED. If RESULT_OK, then continue to let your user use your app.

In the onCreate(), keeping your session code there to check if the user logs in is not a bad idea. Once you return to MainActivity from another Activity and you discover that the user is not logged in, then you can toss them back to your Authentication Activity.

One thing to note about this, you should override onBackPressed() in your login Activity so that the user doesn't get back to MainActivity by accident.

Sample:

## MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean isAuthenticated = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (/* User not logged in */) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AuthenticationActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, AUTHENTICATION_REQ_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == AUTHENTICATION_REQ_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AuthenticationActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, AUTHENTICATION_REQ_CODE);

                // User has cancelled login, redirect back to auth
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // User has logged in
                isAuthenticated = true;
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

## AuthenticationActivity

```
public class AuthenticationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button loginButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do all your checks and if it all goes well, set result to RESULT_OK and finish to
                // MainActivity
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```